# How to edit data in a form with localStorage and angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, local-storage

I have a fill-in form on one page and list on another page, which has an edit button. If I click on the edit button, I should be directed to the page with the form showing the data that I want to edit. I am really stuck with this going to another form page with selected data. Does anyone know how to do this?
**html:**

```
<button class="button" type="button" ng-click="edit()">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
        </button>
```

**controller.js**

```
 $scope.edit = function (value) {     
        $location.path('/add-expense');
        expService.editEntry(value);

    };
```

**services.js:**

```
  //attempt to edit the form   
        editEntry: function (value) {
            var oldValue = localStorage.getItem(value.key);
            value.key = oldValue.key;
            localStorage.setItem(value.key, value);
        },
```

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to do this, which are all equally effective. (There's no one right answer, or even a few best answers.) One option is to store the value of the form to load in the url (or in local storage), and to retrieve it on the second page, and load the correct form.

Comment: Another is simply not to load a second page at all, but to render the new "page" with the right form using JavaScript on the same page. (This is called an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: SPA sounds good, but how to render the new page with the right data when I click edit?

Comment: Depends on how you set up your site. Find a good SPA tutorial written for Angular, and try to follow it. If you get stuck on something specific, we can help you; but [so] is not well equipped to build a whole site, or to make a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store data in the browser's local storage you can simply:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

Then recall it

```
var data = window.localStorage.getItem('key')
```

Remove it

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('key');
```

Though I agree that local storage is not the place to keep form data. It would be better passed to the new page through route parameters, which would require you to use the angularjs routing module, tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Or, change your edit button to look something like:

```
<a href="~/expense/{{expense.ID}}">Edit</a>
```

Then on your server side, load the data for the item your editing using the ID parameter into the result view.

Comment: I managed to edit on the same list using Angular Xeditable. so I managed to just click the list and edit there --> enter new value, save, it shows the new value --> then refresh, it is back to the old value. How come it doesn't save?